Non-blind source separation for binary vector
I have an observation of two sources of signal with one monitor. It produces a binary vector of size n:
\begin{equation}
x^{n} \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
Each position in vector $x$ is sampled either from a source A or a source B.
I have several example vectors of source A.
I want to filter out the bits that are from source A.
I have been looking for any approaches to this type of problem but could not find any material on it. It seems to be a type of non-blind source separation.
Could anybody with experience let me know if this type of problem has a specific name. And if there are any smart solutions to separating the signal, like using ICA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis).

It would be helpful to describe your specific problem in a lot more detail. From what I can tell what you are trying to do has absolutely nothing to do with the Cocktail Party effect (which is primarily a binaural phenomenon involving spatial filtering) but I may be missing something here.

@Hilmar thanks for your response. I adjusted my question to be more specific, and hope it might be more clear why it is related to the cocktail party effect.

Is there any model that describes how a vector from purely source A vs. source B looks like? How are the samples of the vector statistically dependent on each other? If there is no model only (many) examples, you would need data-based/machine learning methods, otherwise we need a model to help you further. I.e., $x = x_A + x_B$ (+any noise?), where $x_A$ and $x_B$ have certain statistics.

@MateC thanks for your response. There is no model of the two data sources only examples. So I presume then that I should look for a more data driven approach.

@GCNN if there is no model at all, no other info, no data but this single binary vector, it is very difficult. Possibly you can try to learn a function $y=g(x)$ whose input is your data vector and output is also an n-vector $y$ that indicates the bits that correspond to source A (for example, $y$ may be also binary with $1$ indicating source A, but that is not the only option). This is a rather particular regression task. You train some machine learning algorithm based on the many examples (with the ``true'' output) you have. I can't quickly help you much further, though.

ICA requires a minimum of $N$ receivers for $N$ channels (note in the video demonstration of this provided by the OP that there are four separate copies of the four video channels each with a different blend of the originals, and with that the four originals can be separated).
The OP made it clear that the application is for one receiver only. One technique that is done with a single receiver and multiple transmitters is Multi-User-Detection. To the extent that at least  one channel can be demodulated (even with relatively high error rates) in the presence of the others, it's contribution to the combined waveform can be recreated and then optimally subtracted using correlation in order to demodulate the others and the process is iteratively repeated to separate all channels.
